# Custom class ordering: no error thrown, what is Python testing for?

Tags: python, object, python-2.x, comparison-operators

Without specifying the equality comparison properties of objects, Python is still doing something when using `>` and `<`. What is Python actually comparing these objects by if you don't specify `__gt__` or `__lt__`? I would expect an unsupported operand error here, as you get when trying to add two objects together without defing `__add__`.

```
In [1]: class MyObject(object):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 
In [2]: class YourObject(object):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 
In [3]: me = MyObject()
In [4]: you = YourObject()
In [5]: me > you
Out[5]: False
In [6]: you > me
Out[6]: True
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An arbitrary order is imposed for objects. The ordering is only defined to be [stable within a program execution](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in).

This means it's up to the Python implementation to define an ordering when comparing arbitrary objects. CPython uses the memory address if the types are the same (from the [C source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/23ebb8936bf6/Objects/object.c#l756)):

```
if (v->ob_type == w->ob_type) {
    /* When comparing these pointers, they must be cast to
     * integer types (i.e. Py_uintptr_t, our spelling of C9X's
     * uintptr_t).  ANSI specifies that pointer compares other
     * than == and != to non-related structures are undefined.
     */
    Py_uintptr_t vv = (Py_uintptr_t)v;
    Py_uintptr_t ww = (Py_uintptr_t)w;
    return (vv < ww) ? -1 : (vv > ww) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

The same value is the basis for the `id()` function, and is also represented in the default `repr()` string for custom classes, so it may *appear* that the `repr()` of classes determine ordering. It's only the memory address that does.

For objects that are *not* the same type, the type *name* is used instead (with number-like types sorting before others), and if the types differ but their *names* are the same, the code falls back to the memory address of the type (as opposed to the memory address of the instance when the types are the same).

This implicit ordering has been considered an error in the language, and has been [remedied in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons):

> The ordering comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `>=`, `>`) raise a `TypeError` exception when the operands don’t have a meaningful natural ordering.

This applies to custom classes that do not implement the necessary [ordering hooks](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__):

```
>>> class Foo(): pass
... 
>>> Foo() < Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: Foo() < Foo()
```

Comment: OK, so its the string representaion of the memory address that is being compared? i.e. `0x162afd0` vs `0x162afd0`

Comment: @reptilicus: it's the actual memory address that is being compared. The *default* `repr()` return value contains a hex representation of the memory address, but that's not what is used for the comparison. You can provide a *custom* `__repr__()` hook for example, and that won't change the ordering (or the memory address).

Comment: @reptilicus It uses the memory if the classes are the same type. Martijn's answer is good and more thorough than my own.

Comment: gotcha. THanks, going to mark this as accepted. I still don't like or understand the logic though!

Comment: @reptilicus: logic is that it was a mistake and it is now fixed in py3k.

Comment: @reptilicus: I've updated my answer to show that things have improved in Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: See the update after reading! The completely correct answer is "undefined, but consistent".

It's testing `repr(me)` vs `repr(you)` which essentially is doing string comparison. Here is an easy to see example:

```
class A(object): pass

class B(object): pass

x = A() # <__main__.A object at 0x7f7014e4e2d0>
y = B() # <__main__.B object at 0x7f7014e4e310>
z = A() # <__main__.A object at 0x7f7014e4e390>

x < z < y # True (assuming that the memory addresses are ordered as above)
```

I agree that this seems a little strange to me. Perhaps there's a good reason for this that I am not aware of?

**UPDATE**: I am wrong about `repr`, though it does look like it uses the base `object` repr in test. http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in

There is a line there that states "The choice whether one object is considered smaller or larger than another one is made arbitrarily but consistently within one execution of a program." In other words, it *might* be using `repr` but that's not guaranteed. It will, however, be consistently done.

Comment: any reference regarding `repr` testing?

Comment: Is there documentation on this?

Comment: This is demonstrably wrong. Custom classes with a `__repr__()` hook cannot alter their ordering by returning different values for `repr(instance)`.

Comment: So, there is nothing whatsoever indicating that `repr` is involved in ordering then.

Comment: OK, so its somewhat random? That seems dangerous and unnecessary to me. Why not just throw an error like the other equality operations?

Comment: @reptilicus "random" isn't quite the right word so much as "undefined". I agree that throwing an error here seems more correct, but maybe there is some good reasoning behind this. Because it is undefined, I could definitely see where this might bite people, especially if they're switching between different Python environments and expecting the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses the object's `repr()` if there are no rich comparison operators. (At least, this is valid for Py2; I don't know for Py3).

So if you do

```
class A(object): pass
class B(object): pass
l = [A() if i % 2 else B() for i in range(1000)]
l.sort()
```

the objects are sorted by their `repr()`, the `A()` coming first and then the `B()`.

Comment: In the case presented above, it is using `repr`, not `id`.

Comment: yeah, Its not the objects ID, I tested that.