# How to compare memoryview object?

Tags: python, memoryview

Does anyone have ideas about the codes below?

```
>>> memoryview("abc") < memoryview("bca")
True
>>> memoryview("abc") > memoryview("bca")
True
>>> memoryview("abc") = memoryview("bca")
False
```

How can I compare the string of memoryview objects without using `tobytes` to get a copy of the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`memoryview()` objects do not define any ordering, it's `__lt__` and `__gt__` methods return the `NotImplemented` singleton indicating that they don't support ordering:

```
>>> memoryview("abc").__lt__(memoryview('bca'))
NotImplemented
>>> memoryview("abc").__gt__(memoryview('bca'))
NotImplemented
```

Thus, Python 2 sorts these using an internal, consistent ordering. In Python 3 a `TypeError` will be raised instead when you attempt to use the `<` and `>` operators.

In python 2, when objects don't support ordering, they are instead ordered by their memory address (for the object itself, not the 'memory' the memoryview is pointing at); see [Custom class ordering: no error thrown, what is Python testing for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456807/custom-class-ordering-no-error-thrown-what-is-python-testing-for/13457344#13457344) for more details on what happens.

Only equality and inequality testing is supported:

```
>>> memoryview("abc").__eq__(memoryview('bca'))
False
>>> memoryview("abc").__eq__(memoryview('abc'))
True
>>> memoryview("abc").__ne__(memoryview('abc'))
False
>>> memoryview("abc").__ne__(memoryview('bca'))
True
```

Your only options are to use `.tobytes()` or `.tolist()`.

Comment: In 2.x since they're the same type it falls back to [comparing the memory address](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Objects/object.c#l750) (object.c, `default_3way_compare`, v2.7.3). Doing the comparison operations in sequential statements with temporary objects causes the addresses to swap for each run. Thus if you repeat the same LT or GT test, the result alternates between True and False.

Comment: @eryksun: I've pointed to my previous answer on the subject now, satisfied? :-)

Comment: It was mostly the line "Python 2 returns False for such operations" that prompted my comment. Though I also found the alternating address allocation from `PyObject_Malloc` kind of interesting, in the way it caused back to back LT/GT tests to both return True.

Comment: @eryksun: Right, that line is indeed wrong. Corrected. Yes, the address re-use is interesting there.